# How to configure a Thoughtworks:GO task to deploy a repo?

Tags: thoughtworks-go

I'm trying to figure out how to create a task (custom-command, not ant/rake, etc) to perform a deployment of a git-repo to some server/target (in this case Heroku). If I were to do this manually, it's just `git push heroku master`.

I've created a basic pipeline/stage/job/task (custom-command, in this case a Python script), and single agent. The pipeline has a material (git repo, with a name). Inside the script, I'm printing out `os.environ.items()` - it has several variables, including the SHA of the latest commit - but no URL for the actual repository.

So how is the agent (or task) supposed to know what repository to deploy?

The pipeline knows the material name, and I've tried passing in an Environment Variable such as ${materialName} (which didn't work). I could hard-code a URL in the task, but that's not a real solution.

Thoughtworks:GO's documentation is shiny, but a bit sparse in the details. I'd have thought something this basic would be well documented, but if so, I haven't found it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a task runs on an agent, it clones the repository specified in the material (config). The .git/config wouldn't have remote Heroku url and as such `git push heroku master` wouldn't work.

You would need to add Heroku remote url before you can perform a deployment of your git-repo to Heroku.

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git`

where project is the name of your Heroku project. This is required to be done only once unless you perform a [clean working directory](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/go/current/help/configuration_reference.html#stage) every time (in Stage Settings which removes all files/directories in the working directory on the agent, you can see this option from the UI as well: Admin -> Piplelines -> Stages -> Stage Settings Tab) in which case you may have to add the remote url via a task before you run the task to deploy.

Once you've done so, you should be able to use the heroku xxxx commands (assuming you have the Heroku Toolbelt installed on the agent machine you are using for deploying), and should be able to push to Heroku as usual via `git push heroku master`.